# SSH ForwardAgent is receiving "Connection closed by remote host"

Tags: ssh, forwarding

I'm trying to connect to a remote server using `SSH ForwardAgent` but I'm facing all the time the same issue :

```
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

I've setup my ~/.ssh/config as follow :

```
#Proxy
Host my.remote.proxy.com
Hostname IPProxy.IP.IP.IP
User my.user
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
ForwardAgent yes

#Remote server
Host my.remote.server.com
Hostname IPRemote.IP.IP.IP
User my.user
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
ProxyCommand ssh my.user@my.remote.proxy.com  nc -w 10 %h %p 2> /dev/null
```

I'm able to ssh correctly into *my.remote.proxy.com*. I'm able to ssh correctly from *my.remote.proxy.com* to *my.remote.server.com* using ssh (and the private on test purpose).

My problem is that I'm not able to ssh from my host to *my.remote.server.com* using forwardagent.

I've setup /etc/ssh/sshd_config for both *my.remote.proxy.com* and *my.remote.server.com* as follow :

```
AllowAgentForwarding yes
AllowTcpForwarding yes
#GatewayPorts no
X11Forwarding yes
```

I checked and both server are using a working version of openssl with forwardagent :

```
openssh-7.4p1-13.el7_4.x86_64
openssh-clients-7.4p1-13.el7_4.x86_64
openssh-server-7.4p1-13.el7_4.x86_64
```

The /var/log/secure from *my.remote.proxy.com* are returning :

```
Nov 15 04:39:07 [localhost] sshd[7866]: Accepted publickey for my.user
Nov 15 04:39:07 [localhost] sshd[7866]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user my.user by (uid=0)
Nov 15 04:39:08 [localhost] sshd[7869]: Received disconnect from IPPUBLIC port 61378:11: disconnected by user
Nov 15 04:39:08 [localhost] sshd[7869]: Disconnected from IPPUBLIC port 61378
Nov 15 04:39:08 [localhost] sshd[7866]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user my.user
```

Nothing is showing up from /var/log/secure on my.remote.server.com.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to used -W instead of nc in order to forward the connexion because the nc packages was not install  remotely on my.remote.server

```
ProxyCommand ssh my.user@my.remote.proxy.com -W %h:%p 2> /dev/null
```

> **-W host:port**
>                Requests that standard input and output on the client be
>                forwarded to host on port over the secure channel.  Implies -N,
>                -T, ExitOnForwardFailure and ClearAllForwardings.  Works with
>                Protocol version 2 only.